# r find index of minima with gap / distance condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, minima

```
list <- c(1,1,1,4,5,6,9,9,2)
```

I want to find the index of the 3 lowest values , but with the condition that the index of the found minima is at least 3 points apart from each other.
To find the 3 lowest indices I'm using

```
which(list <= sort(list, decreasing=FALSE)[3], arr.ind=TRUE)
```

which doesn't look for any conditions and results in

> 1,2,3

My desired result is

> 1,9,4

I want to know if it's possible doing that without any loops since my list is a lot bigger.

Thank you so much in advance.

> To clarify what I meant: The indices of minima must always be in a certain distance. For example for the list `list<-c(1,3,9,5,9,9,2)` the result of the minima should be `1,7,4`. Not `1,7,2`, because that the indices 1 and 2 are too close together. 
>   Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: The conditions are not very clear.  Are you trying to find the index with the distance condition on the `sort`ed vector or the original one

Comment: I'm trying to find the index with the distance condition.

Comment: I meant whether the distance is in the origingal vector or sorted

Comment: the distance refers to the indices of the original vector.

Comment: Can't anyone help? I would really appreciate it since I am stuck. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using dplyr:
create a dataframe with sequence in the 2nd column, then sort and find first occurance

```
library(dplyr)

kk <- data.frame(cbind(list, seq=seq_along(list))) %>% 
    arrange(list) %>%  # sort list
    group_by(list) %>% # group
    summarise(V3=min(seq)) %>% # find first occurance
    .$V3 %>% # get sequence values  
    head(3) # get top 3

[1] 1 9 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. There is a problem when the Minima occur in a different order. For example for `c(1,3,9,5,9,9,2)` I would expect **1,7,4** but I get **1,7,2**